# ARP binary for MIPS64 (big-endian) compatible with Linux v2.6

Tags: linux, binary, mips

Where can I find an ARP binary for the MIPS64 (big-endian) CPU compatible with Linux v2.6 ?

By "ARP binary" I mean a standalone compiled binary executable of the ARP command that manipulates the Address Resolution Protocol tables.

By "standalone" I mean NOT a part of some big multi-purpose shell package like the "Busybox".

I find it very hard to cross-compile anything for the MIPS64 CPU (I would not even know where to start).

Comment: What system are you running and why? Maybe some background information can help spark new ideas, for example I found a wake on lan binary for my OpenWRT/Lede based router by digging in some packages for a similar system.

Comment: Linux v2.6.21.7 for Cavium-Octeon CN5010-SCP

Comment: This is somewhat similar...but no binaries :(     https://github.com/odit/rv042

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson Cavium offers SDKs with Toolchains after registration on their website. I got a toolchain for the MIPS64 working this way, what was tricky is that different "flavors" of 64 bit exist (o32, o64, n32, n64 I believe).